problem in reloading iframe with updated src
So I have a window where there is an Iframe named containerframe and within that iframe I have another iframe named pcpFrame.
From pcpFrame Iframe I postMessage to raise a message event for the grandparent (parent iframe's parent) using :
window.parent.parent.postMessage(message, '*');
In the grand-parent window I am listening to message event and execute following piece of code :
window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    // Get the sent data
    let iframe = window.document.getElementById("containerframe");
    console.log('data json', e.data)
    let msg = JSON.parse(e.data)
    if (msg?.refresh == true){
        alert("updating iframe");
        iframe.src = "https://codepen.io/pen/";
        // iframe.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
        alert("updated");
    }
});


Expected behavior :
Initially the parent iframe (called containerFrame) has pre-loaded webpage with src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qz0aGYrrlhU" and after processing this message event I want to reload this parent iframe with updated src='https://codepen.io/pen'
Actually behavior :
What currently happens is that, this reloads the parent iframe (containerFrame) but instead of loading the iframe with updated src='https://codepen.io/pen/', it re-fetches the webpage with original iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qz0aGYrrlhU'

There are two strange things :

After message event is processed (and not debugging) I saw some conflict through some console logging :
console.log(iframe.src) // prints updated src for codepen page
console.log(iframe.contentDocument.location) // prints previous src for youtube page
similar thing gets reflected in the HTML elements panel too :

<iframe id="containerframe" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" style="z-index: -1; overflow-x: hidden;" onload="setIframeHeight(this)" height="1119.2px" src="https://codepen.io/pen/">
#document (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qz0aGYrrlhU)
<html>
<! –– rest of the code removed as no issue here ––>
</html>
</iframe>


If I do this while debugging the callback of message event, iframe loads page from upated src, i.e. codepen webpage


The location and src values for iframe are little weird, as they don’t get updated when the content of the iframe changes. This is a security and anti-tracking thing, so that the parent page can’t track what the user does in the iframe.
If you want to refresh the content in the iframe after the page has undated you’ll need to use URL cache busting. Basically you add a ? followed by a random string to the URL when you update iframe.src.
iframe.src = `https://codepen.io/pen/?${Math.random()}`


You only need a cache buster if the old and new URL would be the same and you have to prevent retrieving the contents from cache. I don't see what this has to do with the question.

Why else would he want to reload the page?

They're changing from a youtube URL to a codepen URL, according to the question.

I was looking at this line in his code  iframe.contentWindow.location.reload(true).

I was looking at the text of the question, where it says "after processing this message event I want to reload this parent iframe with updated src='https://codepen.io/pen'"
